# Dart store prime numbers in array

Tags: dart, for-loop, arraylist, primes

May I know how to store the N prime numbers, which I got from for loop in an array in dart?

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  // print('enter a start number');
  // int a = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
  print('enter a  number');
  int b = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
  print('this are prime numbers');
  primenum(b);
  var z = '';
}

primenum(b) {
  String string = "";
  int a = 2;
  outerLoop:
  for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
    for (int x = 2; x <= i / a; x++) {
      if (i % x == 0) {
        continue outerLoop;
      }
    }

    var z = i.toString();

    // print(z);
    var h = z;
    //  String str = '';
    string = string + h;
  }
  List d = string.split('');
  print(d);
}
```

Using the above code, I am able to get those numbers in List. But the double-digit numbers are splitting.

May I know How to solve the above task? using dart.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're doing `string.split` is splitting the string into a list of each individual character. Instead, you can add each prime number to a List directly without doing string manipulation.

```html
primenum(b) {
  List<String> d;
  int a = 2;
  outerLoop:
  for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
    for (int x = 2; x <= i / a; x++) {
      if (i % x == 0) {
        continue outerLoop;
      }
    }

    d.add(i.toString());
  }
  print(d);
}
```

Comment: Tried doing this method, but I am getting an exception.

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: Unhandled exception:
NoSuchMethodError: The method 'add' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: add("2")
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
#1      primenum (file:///Users/drole/Documents/Projects/dart/dart_application_1/bin/listfilesinDirectory.dart:24:7)
#2      main (file:///Users/drole/Documents/Projects/dart/dart_application_1/bin/listfilesinDirectory.dart:9:3)
#3      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:307:19)
#4      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:174:12)

Comment: Okay sorry I was just writing the code straight to Stack Overflow. It should be d.add, I'll edit the answer